# How to reset default tab indentation in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, indentation

pressing Enter key on a line in a cell now places cursor at 35 spaces to the right of 1st column on the next line due to who knows what.

Pressing Tab key while in 1st column goes to same place: 35 spaces to the right.
This adds keystrokes to what was before comfortable and routine.
Is there a fix?
Thanks

Comment: Does this occur in a brand new notebook? Have you made sure to restart in order to clear out "junk". Assuming you didn't do this on purpose, it seems unlikely a setting has changed (such as a default tab width option).

Comment: No, it doesn't. I had tried shutting everything down, even the PC, and restarting, opening up the offending notebook upon reboot. I just created a new notebook and it appears to be back to normal. Thanks!

Comment: Okay great! I can only think it somehow was "detecting" that the current code block was indented (like what you usually want when you are in an if block for example ... to start the next line at the same level of indentation).

Comment: Precisely. I copied code from the offending notebook, pasted it into the new notebook and the misbehavior re-appeared. Dang! Start from scratch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop Jupyter auto-indenting new lines a large, non-integer amount of tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56873736/stop-jupyter-auto-indenting-new-lines-a-large-non-integer-amount-of-tabs)